# int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, api, kotlin, weather-api

I am trying to convert the `JSONObject` to an `JSONArray` but it gives me an `Exception`. I have tried changing if else to try catch block also but it has no result.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val CITY: String="Delhi,In"
    val API: String= "67561777e881bf52c2b82163225846ad"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        wetherTask().execute()
    }
    inner class wetherTask() :AsyncTask<String,Void,String>()
    {
        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()
            findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.loader).visibility= View.VISIBLE
            findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.maincontainer).visibility=View.GONE
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.errortext).visibility=View.GONE
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg  params: String?): String? {
            var response:String?
            try {
                response =URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$CITY&units=metric&APPID=$API")
                    .readText(Charsets.UTF_8)
                System.out.println(response);

            }
            catch (e:Exception)
            {
                response=null
            }
            return response
    }


        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            try {
                val jasonObj= JSONObject(result)
                val main=jasonObj.getJSONObject("main")
                val sys=jasonObj.getJSONObject("sys")
                val wind=jasonObj.getJSONObject("wind")
                val weather=jasonObj.getJSONObject("weather")

                val updateAt:Long=jasonObj.getLong("dt")
                val updateAtText="Update at: "+SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH).format(Date(updateAt*1000))
                val temp=main.getString("temp")+"°C"
                val tempMin="Min Temp: "+main.getString("temp_min")+"°C"
                val tempMax="Max Temp: "+main.getString("temp_max")+"°C"
                val pressure= main.getString("pressure")
                val humidity=main.getString("humidity")
                val sunrise:Long=sys.getLong("sunrise")
                val sunset:Long=sys.getLong("sunset")
                val windSpeed=wind.getString("speed")
                val weatherDescription=weather.getString("description")
                val address=jasonObj.getString("name")+", "+sys.getString("country")

                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.adress).text=address
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.update_at).text=updateAtText
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.status).text=weatherDescription.capitalize()
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.temp).text=temp
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.temp_min).text=tempMin
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.temp_max).text=tempMax
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sunrise).text=SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a",Locale.ENGLISH).format((Date(sunrise*1000)))
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sunset).text=SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a",Locale.ENGLISH).format((Date(sunset*1000)))
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.wind).text=windSpeed
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pressure).text=pressure
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.humidity).text=humidity

                findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.loader).visibility=View.GONE
                findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.maincontainer).visibility=View.VISIBLE
            }
            catch (e:Exception){
                System.out.println(e);
                findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.loader).visibility=View.GONE
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.errortext).visibility=View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
}
}
```

```
1st error-
2022-12-01 13:32:16.389 5990-5990/com.example.wheather I/System.out: org.json.JSONException: Value {"coord":{"lon":77.2167,"lat":28.6667},"weather":[{"id":711,"main":"Smoke","description":"smoke","icon":"50d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":23.05,"feels_like":22.61,"temp_min":23.05,"temp_max":23.05,"pressure":1015,"humidity":46},"visibility":1500,"wind":{"speed":2.57,"deg":280},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1669881717,"sys":{"type":1,"id":9165,"country":"IN","sunrise":1669857989,"sunset":1669895639},"timezone":19800,"id":1273294,"name":"Delhi","cod":200} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

2nd Error-
2022-12-01 16:38:42.435 6838-6838/com.example.wheather I/System.out: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using retrofit for this task, it will cover the entire process of API request an parsing the result. Here is a good example for your case:
https://github.com/Jeluchu/retrofitAPI

Also please do not use AsyncTask - it is deprecated try using coroutines instead.